# VectorGraphics Unity3d - get reference to imported SVG in code

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector-graphics

I am using Unity's [Vector Graphics package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.vectorgraphics@1.0/manual/index.html) to import a simple svg with 3 shapes.

Importing works successfully:

[image]

However, once imported - how do I get a reference to the svg - so that I can modify shapes and fills?

The documentation shows how to render (after making changes) but I don't understand how to *first get the reference to the imported svg?*

Even seeing some sample code that has been implemented would be enough but I can't find any online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this would be to parse the SVG file to get a vector representation of the file (vector Scene), then you can change any properties before tessellation. For example:

```
string svg =
    @"<svg xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"" xmlns:xlink=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"" viewBox=""0 0 216 216"">
       <g>
           <polygon id=""Poly1"" points=""...""/>
       </g>
   </svg>";

// Import the SVG at runtime
var sceneInfo = SVGParser.ImportSVG(new StringReader(svg));
var shape = sceneInfo.NodeIDs["Poly1"].Shapes[0];
shape.Fill = new SolidFill() { Color = Color.red };

// Tessellate
var geoms = VectorUtils.TessellateScene(sceneInfo.Scene, tessOptions);

// Build a sprite
var sprite = VectorUtils.BuildSprite(geoms, 10.0f, VectorUtils.Alignment.Center, Vector2.zero, 128, true);
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprite;
```

[See source answer](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-ui-svg-support-script.551254/page-2#post-4364425)